# How can I make this python function run O(log n) time instead of O(n) time?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer

```
def findMax(f,c):
    n=1
    while f(n) <= c:
        n += 1
   return n
```

This is a higher-order python function that given function f and a maximal count,
c returns the largest n such that f(n) ≤ c. This works but not when n gets too large for e.g `f(10**6)`. How can I make this algorithm run O(log n) time so it can facilitate `f(10**6)` using the function below?

```
def f(n):
    return math.log(n, 2)
```

Comment: Is `f` guaranteed to be monotonic?

Comment: Is the result of f(n) proportionally increasing relative to n? You could just do a binary traversal.

Comment: Is `findMax()` called repeatedly?   That is, would it be productive to cache its results?

Comment: Without more information on the nature of `f`, there's no way to do better.

Comment: *"returns the largest n such that f(n) ≤ c"*: it seems to return the *smallest*

Comment: We need the code of  `f` to help you.

Comment: This is returning the first positive integer such that `f(n)` is *greater* than `c`, not the largest `n` such that `f(n) <= c`.

Comment: How are you even supposed to know whether you've found the highest `n`? For all you know, no matter how high you've searched, some higher `n` could have `f(n) <= c`.

Comment: This is the third time this question has been asked today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935621/algorithm-in-ologn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931413/an-higher-order-function-that-returns-the-largest-n-such-that-fn-a-given-ma

Comment: @Kevin I've provided an example of  `f` where `findMax()` takes forever to run.

Answer (score 0):

Change `n += 1` to `n *= 2` for logarithmic outcome.

Logarithmic sequences increment ***in multiples of 2***, and are *non-linear*, thus logarithmic sequences don't increment by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use a search algorithm to find the solution faster. This is an implementation using jpe.math.framework.algorythems.brent which is an implementation of the brent search algorithm.

```
import math
import jpe

import jpe.math.framework.algorythems

def f(x):
    return math.log(x, 2)

value = 9E2
startVal = 1E300

val = int(jpe.math.framework.algorythems.brent(f, a=0, b=startVal, val=value, mode=jpe.math.framework.algorythems.modes.equalVal)[0])#takes 37 iters

print(val)
```

Alternatively in this scenario with this f:

the result is within 1 of 2**c (c as passedto findMax)